# How do I get a value greater than a specified value in rest assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am a newbie to Rest-Assured api using Java. I want to extract the number of days the temperature of a city is above 18 . Using openweathermap.org.

The url is api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Sydney&units=metric&appid={APP KEY}

I get :

```
{
    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0.0067,
    "cnt": 40,
    "list": [
        {
            "dt": 1557727200,
            "main": {
                "temp": 20.88,
                "temp_min": 20.88,
                "temp_max": 21.05,
                "pressure": 1025.56,
                "sea_level": 1025.56,
                "grnd_level": 1021.14,
                "humidity": 57,
                "temp_kf": -0.17
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 803,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "broken clouds",
                    "icon": "04d"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 55
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 3.45,
                "deg": 43.754
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "d"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2019-05-13 06:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1557738000,
            "main": {
                "temp": 18.45,
                "temp_min": 18.45,
                "temp_max": 18.58,
                "pressure": 1026.06,
                "sea_level": 1026.06,
                "grnd_level": 1021.28,
                "humidity": 73,
                "temp_kf": -0.13
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 804,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "overcast clouds",
                    "icon": "04n"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 100
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 3.84,
                "deg": 28.267
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "n"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2019-05-13 09:00:00"
        },  {
            "dt": 1557759600,
            "main": {
                "temp": 14.31,
                "temp_min": 14.31,
                "temp_max": 14.35,
                "pressure": 1026.29,
                "sea_level": 1026.29,
                "grnd_level": 1021.87,
                "humidity": 80,
                "temp_kf": -0.04
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 802,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "scattered clouds",
                    "icon": "03n"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 28
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 1.66,
                "deg": 279.19
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "n"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2019-05-13 15:00:00"
        },
       
}
```

I am unsure how do i proceed with the iterations. It would be a great help if someone can help me through.

I am able to get the data but not sure how do I get the element from each array

Now, I want to extract the temperatures which are above 18 degrees

I have attempted the below:

```java
public class WeatherForecast {
    
    public static Response resp;
    
    @Test
    public void getWeatherForecastForCity()
    {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://api.openweathermap.org";
        

        
        resp = given().
               param("q", "Sydney").
               param("units", "metric").
               param("appid", "670473f82ba0969a884be548c75236a4").
        when().
                get("/data/2.5/forecast").
        then().
                extract().response();
        
        List<String> temperatures = resp.getBody().jsonPath().getList("list");
        //String value = temperatures.getString()
        int count = temperatures.size();
        for(int i=0;i<=count;i++)
            
        {
            
        }
        System.out.println("List Size: "+temperatures.size());
        
        //assertEquals(temperatures, greaterThanOrEqualTo(20.00F));
        
        //String responseString = resp.asString();
        //System.out.println("Response String: "+responseString);
        //JsonPath js = new JsonPath(responseString);
        
        //Get the number of records for the city
        //int size = js.getList("list").size();
        //int temperature = Integer.parseInt(js.get("count"));
        //System.out.println("Temperature Value: "+js.getString("list[1].main.temp"));
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Check my answer. I already tested the solution with JSON you provided and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RestAssured`uses a powerful library called `JsonPath` which you already used.

The difference of what you already creates is how to get JSONObject/Array inside other JSONObject/Array

You used `resp.getBody().jsonPath().getList("list");` which is almost a good starting point. Instead of using `List<String>` you should use `List<HashMap<String, Object>>`

Each `HashMap<>` will be a JSON Object.

Then you can just iterate over the Array to get each object and temperatures.

How to do that:

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = resp.getBody().jsonPath().getList("list");
for (HashMap<String, Object> jsonObject : list) {
    /**
    * Now, in order to get temperature, we have to get access to `main` element in JSON and then get access to the temperature
    **/
    HashMap<String, Object> mainElements = (HashMap<String, Object>) jsonObject.get("main");
    //No we have JSONObject as HashMap. We can access any temperature
    float temperature = (float) mainElements.get("temp");
    System.out.println(temperature);
}
```

The above code will print all temperatures. Now you just have to compare float values, save them, assert them or do whatever you want :)

You can access any value with this approach

**EDIT:**
Extract the above code to a method like this:

```
    private List<HashMap<String, Object>> getJsonObjectsWithTempGreaterThan(JsonPath path, float degrees) {
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> desiredJsonObjects = new ArrayList<>();

        List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = path.getList("list");
        for (HashMap<String, Object> jsonObject : list) {
            HashMap<String, Object> mainElements = (HashMap<String, Object>) jsonObject.get("main");
            float temperature = (float) mainElements.get("temp");
            if (temperature > degrees) {
                desiredJsonObjects.add(jsonObject);
            }
        }

        return desiredJsonObjects;
    }
```

Above code will store each of JSON Object in a List and then return it. The list will contain JSON Objects with a temperature greater than degrees passed in the parameter.

Then, you can access those elements like this:

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> objects = getJsonObjectsWithTempGreaterThan(path, 20);
```

This is our list of desired objects.
If you just want the temperatures, all you have to do is:

```
for (HashMap<String, Object> jsonObject : objects) {
    HashMap<String, Object> mainElements = (HashMap<String, Object>) jsonObject.get("main");
    //No we have JSONObject as HashMap. We can access any temperature
    float temperature = (float) mainElements.get("temp");
    System.out.println(temperature);
}
```

This can be achieved much more easily and readable with Java Streams.

Comment: Wow. That worked like a charm. Thanks for that. My intention is to get  number of days where temperature is greater than 20 Degrees

Comment: @Amit Do you need additional help? If not, accept my answer :)

Comment: Yes sure, will do . Could you please let me know how to do that.

Comment: @Amit Check again :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Learnt new things today. Is there anything i need to do about the thread now , like accept or close or something else ? not sure . any pointers, really appreciated.

Comment: @Amit Read the short instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) You should accept my answer :)

Comment: @Amit You're welcome. Have fun and don't hesitate to ask questions in the future. Just make sure they are described fully to understand the problem :)